# Is it possible to automatically open a video modal and begin playing only when the user accesses the page from a link in an email.?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, url, url-routing

I know that we can open Bootstrap modal on page load very easily. But I have a situation where the modal should open ONLY when the user accesses the page from an email link?

Is there any way to do using JavaScript or JQuery.

Comment: Yes! short answer.

Comment: @Jai Could you please share how to do that in Js or jQuery

Comment: Simly put code on  `onload` event .  Like `model.open(); video.play();` inside the onload function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can.

The most straightforward way I can think of is to use an extra query parameter in the url used in the email.

When your page loads, you can test for this query parameter and then decide to open your modal or not.

Consider this sample URL:

`www.example.com`

In the email version, we can add a query parameter like this :

`www.example.com?email=true`

and then, on your client side (on page load):

```
 var query = window.location.href.split('?')[1];
 if(query && query.indexOf('email=true') > -1){
     // Url has the parameter run code to open modal
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this

Just you have to pass extra parameter ( querystring) in the Link.

Suppose your Normal link is "www.xyz.com", instead of this you have to pass "www.xyx.com?bylink"

and on your page load you have to get the page Url & find the extra parameter  (querystring)

If the parameter is there in the URL just open the Video Popup or else Open the page normally .

Eg:

```
var URL =window.location.href ;
if(URL.contains('bylink'))
{
videoModel.show();
}
else{
NoramlPage.show();
}
```